# Payflow VeriSign Endpoint Deprecation

Tags: magento-enterprise, payment, magento-community, paypal-payflow-pro

PayPal published a help page: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1299 saying that certain verisign.com URLs are going to be deprecated.

```
payments.verisign.com
payflowpro.verisign.com
payflow.verisign.com
cr-payflow.verisign.com
```

Does this change affect Magento CE or EE? They recommend changing the verisign.com urls to paypal.com urls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I searched throough the PayPal methods and found that at least 1.7 CE and later use the paypal.com urls. This change should not affect modern versions of Magento.